# Optimize way to compare oracle data between two tables using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, compression, comparison

For large dataset from oracle table, I want to perform comparison using python. Can anyone guide the optimize(faster) way for doing this in python (using cx_oracle module)

I have tried storing two sqls output in two different dataframes and looping each cell for comparison. But it is taking ages to finish.

```
for row in range(dfrow):
    for col in range(dfcol):
        value_old = sorted_t.iloc[row, col]
        value_new = sorted_p.iloc[row, col]
        if value_old != value_new:
            dfdiff.iloc[row, col] = ({} -> {}).format(value_old, value_new)
```

I expect any faster way of doing such comparison.

Comment: If the dataset is really large, can you find a way to do the comparison in SQL or PL/SQL so you don't have the cost of transferring all the rows from the DB into Python?

Answer (score 1):

You populated your T and P dataframes with a query like

```
select id, a, b, c
from p;
```

It sounds like there's a large number of rows in T and P,
and typically they match.
You would like to rapidly skip the matching rows.
Well, just don't even drag them into memory,
let oracle filter out the matches:

```
select t.id, t.a, t.b, t.c,
       p.id, p.a, p.b, p.c
from   t
join   p on t.id = p.id
where  t.a != p.a
       or t.b != p.b
       or t.c != t.c;
```

Use whatever fancy formatting you like to display those filtered values.

Comment: But both database is on different server. However, i am filtering out matched rows by merging two dataframe and doing dropduplicate in merged dataframe, then again splitting dataframe based on P and T column came from respective database. Now the splitted dataframe is being compared by this for loop which is taking lot of time.

Comment: This solution works perfectly with tables (in the same database) that contain ~10 million records. Thanks, J_H !